# ISS7 authentication doesn't work on servername

Tags: iis-7, authentication

Not sure if I put correct title but here is my problem:

Local (home network) IIS 7, default web site bind to any IP on port 81, Anonymous Auth disabled, Windows Auth enabled

If I go to 192.168.1.101:81/ I get asked for username and password.

If I go to server:81/ nothing is being asked regardless whether connecting from local or another machine on the network.

Why is that? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This probably has to do with the IIS bindings.  Go to your website and click on the Bindings link from the Actions pane.  Those bindings need to catch servername, with the IP or (all unassigned) that servername resolves to.

Either site your isn't being caught at all or it's being caught by another site on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out [Intranet site is identified as an Internet site when you use an FQDN or an IP address](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303650)